# How to sort an array by a particular value?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to sort the output by grouping the string into a particular category.
As you may tell from my code, i have the values for the categories team name, league, coaches, division and full time in a single string/line. I would like to sort the each string/line by the league name. For instance, all the teams with the league "Western" in the string will be grouped together, and all the teams with the league "Eastern" will be grouped together.

Code:

Team.java:

```
public class Team 
{
private String name;
private String league;
private String[] coaches;
private String division;
private boolean fullTime;

public Team(String dataLine)
{
    String[] data = dataLine.split(",");
    this.name = data[0];

    this.coaches = getStringAsArray(data[1], ":");

    this.league = data[2];

    this.division = data[3];

    this.fullTime = data[4].equals("yes");      

}

public Team(){

}

private String[] getStringAsArray(String t, String delimiter)
{
    String[] result = t.split(delimiter);
    return result;
}

private String getArrayAsString(String[] coaches)
{

    coaches = this.getCoaches();
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<coaches.length; i++)
    {
        result += coaches[i] +" ";
    }
    result = result.trim();
    return result;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setCoaches(String coaches)
{
    this.coaches = getStringAsArray(coaches, ":");
}

public String getCoachesAsString()
{

    String result = getArrayAsString(coaches);
    return result;
}

public boolean isFullTime() {
    return fullTime;
}

public void setFullTime(boolean fullTime) {
    this.fullTime = fullTime;
}

public String getDivision() {
    return division;
}

public void setDivision(String division) {
    this.division = division;
}

public String[] getCoaches() {
    return coaches;
}

public void setCoaches(String[] coaches) {
    this.coaches = coaches;
}

public String getLeague() {
    return league;
}

public void setLeague(String league) {
    this.league = league;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " Team name: " + name + ", League: " + this.league + ", Coaches: " + Arrays.toString(this.coaches) +  ", Division: " + this.division + ", Full Time: " + this.fullTime + "\n ";
}
}
```

StoreData.java:

```
public class StoreData {
public static ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

public static String getTeams()
{
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++){
        s += teams.get(i);

    }
    return s;
}

public static ArrayList<Team> TeamListFromArray(String[] as)
{
     ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    // for( int i= 0 ; i < as.length; i++){
     for (String s: as){
        teams.add(new Team(s));
     }
     return teams;
}

}
```

FootballC.java:

```
public class FootballC {
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ReadCsv junk = new ReadCsv();
    junk.readCsv();
    System.out.println(StoreData.getTeams());
}
}
```

ReadCSV.java:

```
public class ReadCsv {

public void readCsv() {

    String csvFileToRead = "H:/Desktop/FootballRepo/TestData/football_teams_phase1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Team one = new Team(line);
            if(i > 0){
                 StoreData.teams.add(new Team(line));
            }else{
               i++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Team> getTeams() {
    return StoreData.teams;
}

public static void setTeams(ArrayList<Team> teams) {
    StoreData.teams = teams;
}
}
```

Comment: what are you asking for? grouping or sorting?

Comment: it is not array, it is collection `ArrayList<Team> teams` , so Java 8 stream API should work just fine for both grouping and sorting, give it a try [https://leanpub.com/whatsnewinjava8/read#leanpub-auto-streams]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
final String[] input = /* get input from anywhere */;
Arrays.sort(input, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        String[] dataA = a.split(",");
        String leagueA = dataA[2];
        String[] dataB = b.split(",");
        String leagueB = dataB[2];
        return leagueA.compareTo(leagueB);
    }
});
```

It can sort your teams before even creating their according objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming team.league is not null

Sorting:

```
teams.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Team::getLeague))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Grouping:

```
teams.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Team::getLeague))
        .forEach((l,t) -> System.out.println("League: " + l + ", Teams: " + t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the list of teams you can group the objects like this:

```
{
    public static Map<String, List<Team>> makeGroup(List<Team> teams) {
        Map<String, List<Team>> teamMap = new HashMap<String, List<Team>>();
        for (Team team : teams) {
            if (!teamMap.containsKey(team.getLeague())) {
                teamMap.put(team.getLeague(), new ArrayList<Team>());
            }

            List<Team> list = teamMap.get(team.getLeague());
            list.add(team);
        }
        return teamMap;
    }
}
```

Further if you want to sort the teams, you can do it as [MinecraftShamrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324078/minecraftshamrock) mentioned above.

Comment: note - https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap nicely replaces this boilerplate